# Not recognized as internal user in console.cloud.google.com

Tags: google-cloud-platform, internals, google-shopping

I am configuring oauth consent screen console.cloud.google.com and want to configure the project with user-type 'internal user'. I am a workspace user. Google tells me that I am not. How can I configure the Oauth screen for an internal user ?

Configuring the API with a user of type 'Internal user'.

In the admin console I am an active user.